# How to resolve mutual dependencies between a main script and submodules needing access to a global variable from the script?

Tags: python, import, module, organization, typer

I'm building a [Typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/) app with lots of commands. I want to categorize the commands into subfiles but am unsure how to resolve the dependencies.

```
|
├── melvil
│   ├── add.json
│   ├── book
│   │   ├── book.py
│   │   └── __init__.py      
│   ├── booklist
│   │   ├── booklist.py
│   │   └── __init__.py 
│   ├── helper
│   │   ├── helper.py
│   │   └──__init__.py  
│   ├── search
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── search.py
│   │
│   │
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── setup.py
│   └── test_input.txt
```

`main.py` is the parent. It looks like this:

```
import typer
from datetime import date

app = typer.Typer()

# Import submodules
from booklist.booklist import *
from book.book import *
from search.search import *
from helper.helper import *

# App is only invoked when we run main.py directly, but not when we import it.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

So, we make a new Typer `app` and import everything from the submodules. Simple enough.

Each of the submodules contains Typer commands, like `booklist`:

```
# This file focuses on commands that affect the entire booklist.

import inquirer
import os
import json
import csv

@app.command()
def delete():
    """
    ...Irrelevant code here...
    """
```

**Here's the problem:** in order to define a Typer command with the `@app.command()` decorator, each submodule first needs to import `app` from the parent `main.py`. However, `main.py` gets run in the import statement for any of the submodules, and so a circular import arises when `main.py` imports whatever submodule it's in.

How should one structure this project so that all submodules have access to `app` and `main.py` can also access all the submodules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just have `app` be initialized in its own separate module. Let the sub-modules import it from there and have your `main` module import those sub-modules.

Something like this:
`app.py`

```py
import typer

app = typer.Typer()
```

`booklist.py`

```py
from YOURTOPLEVELPACKAGE.app import app

@app.command()
def your_function():
    ...
```

`main.py`

```py
# All of those include `app`
from booklist.booklist import *
from book.book import *
from search.search import *
from helper.helper import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
      app()
```

Comment: This solution worked with the small caveat that a sys.path hack (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) seemed necessary to import app from the parent folder.